DNA results different for 2 cousins
I recently did an Ancestry DNA test and my 1st cousin has done one a while back.
Her mum and my dad were siblings.
Her maternal side shows she is 50% Irish and for me my paternal side shows 48% Irish and 2% French.
How do we show different results when our parents were siblings?

Ethnicity estimates are educated guesses, based on reference populations and particular features in the DNA. Ancestry explains how they get to their conclusions in reports called white papers, which you can download from AncestryDNA® White Papers.

Ancestral regions
Our ancestral regions white paper outlines the science behind our
statistical estimation of the historical origins of your DNA. By
comparing the DNA of the people in our database to the DNA of people
of each region in our global reference panel, we determine the degree
of similarity and create an estimate based on that analysis.

Ancestry compares DNA from testers like you to groups of people who are living in different countries whose families have lived there for a specified amount of time. These are called reference populations.  So someone gets assigned an estimate of being Irish because their tests matches up with the reference group from Ireland and so on.
While siblings get 50% of their DNA from each parent, they don't get the same 50% of their parents' DNA.  For your paternal side, some feature in your DNA must have matched with the reference population Ancestry got from its reference population for France.
Since different companies use different reference populations, and look at the data in different ways, it's entirely possible that if you and your cousin submitted tests to different DNA companies, you'd get different results than what Ancestry is telling you.  If companies update their method of analysis, estimates can change over time. It's very fluid, and should only be used as a general guide.
Over the years, Judy G. Russell has tracked the changes in DNA tests on her blog The Legal Genealogist. You can find all her posts about DNA by looking for posts tagged DNA.
She has written many times about the fluidity of DNA estimates, comparing them humorously to the old Campbell's Soup commercial which had the tagline "Is it soup yet?"  My favorite of the series: Still Not Soup

Those "ethnicity" estimates are just that: estimates. Anything under 10% may be pure chance, a.k.a. fiction, and even the larger numbers have entertainment value only.
The fact is, geography is not genetic, no matter what the DNA companies want you to think.

I was reminded just now of a data tidbit supporting the "entertainment value only" characterization of ethnicity estimates: one of the companies assigns different percentages to me and my identical twin. (The other companies each only have one of our tests, so no comparison can be made there.)
